# Disable Apple ID signup popup in Macos

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

How to disable this? I don't want to use Apple services
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icon is for the Mac App Store, and the dialog says "To continue", so either you or some other process must have triggered it.

Just press Cancel. Bear in mind that you can't use the Mac App Store without an AppleID, so if you have an apps like Pages, Logic, you can't update or download them.

Comment: This is not really an answer. It keeps popping up every other day. How do I "perma-cancel"?